# Split into two columns and convert txt text into a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data:

```
Graudo. A selection of Pouteria caimito, a minor member...

TtuNextrecod. A selection of Pouteria caimito, a minor member of the Sapotaceae...
```

I want to split it into two columns

```
Column1       Column2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Graudo        A selection of Pouteria caimito, a minor member...
TtuNextrecod  A selection of Pouteria caimito, a minor member of the Sapotaceae...
```

Need help with the code. Thanks,

```
import csv # convert
import itertools #function for a efficient looping

with open('Abiutxt.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines() #returns a list with all the lines in string, including the line breaks

    test = [line.split('. ')for line in lines ] #split period....but...need work

    print(test)


    stripped = [line.replace('', '').split('. ')for line in lines ]

    grouped = itertools.izip(*[stripped]*1)
    with open('logtestAbiutxt.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Column1', 'Column2'))

        for group in grouped:
            writer.writerows(group)
```

Comment: I got it: I replaced for stripped = [line.split('. ', 1)for line in lines ]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you need zipping here at all. Simply iterate over every line of the input file, skip empty lines, split by the period and write to the csv file:

```
import csv


with open('Abiutxt.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('logtestAbiutxt.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter="\t")
        writer.writerow(['Column1', 'Column2'])

        for line in in_file:
            if not line.strip():
                continue

            writer.writerow(line.strip().split(". ", 1))
```

Notes:

- Note: specified a tab as a delimiter, but you could change it appropriately
- thanks to @PatrickHaugh for the idea to split by the first occurence of `". "` only as your second column may contain periods as well.

Comment: I think `split(". ", 1)` could be necessary here, their Column2 data looks like it might have periods in it.

Comment: @Viktor we need more details please. Getting any errors?

Comment: None error, is not adding the data into two columns. That's it. My code work....anyhow, thanks for the message.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want. This will handle all the escaping.

```
import csv
with open('Abiutxt.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    x = in_file.read().splitlines()
    x = [line.split('. ', 1) for line in x if line]
with open('logtestAbiutxt.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Column1', 'Column2']) 
    writer.writerows(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, eatmeimadanish. Works but need columns...anyhow, thanks,

Comment: What do you mean it needs columns?  It has columns... 2 columns just like you stated in your question...

Comment: That's correct. It hast two columns. I meant to say, missing just the name from the second columns. It's working. Thanks,

Comment: I didn't realize you actually needed columns that said, column1 and column2... seems completely pointless